# Userform : Index Match condition

Tags: excel, vba

i have my userform that consist of supplier(combobox1), product (combobox2), unit price(textbox1)

I wish when i choose the supplier and product in userform, the unit price will be auto lookup the excel data sheet (AddProduct) and get the unit price result.

In AddProduct sheet, I have my supplier at column A2:A10, product at column B2:B10 and unit price at column C2:C10

I have my code like this:

```
Dim ReturnVal As Variant


ReturnVal = Evaluate("=INDEX('AddProduct'!$C$2:$C$10,MATCH(1,(""" & Me.ComboBox1.Value & """='AddProduct'!$A$2:$A$10)*(""" & Me.ComboBox2.Value & """='AddProduct'!$B$2:$B$10),0))")


If Not IsError(ReturnVal) Then
    Me.TextBox1.Value = ReturnVal
Else
    Me.TextBox1.Value = "N/A"


End If
```

The fact for the form is it will return N/A although I have insert data inside AddProduct sheet.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is:

1) Insert a helper column. Insert a new Column A on "AddProduct".  In that column add the following formula:

```
= B2 & C2
```

which concatenates the supplier and product into one string.  This column can be hidden if wanted. And if you make the whole column with this relative formula you will not have to worry about new products it will always put the value in column A.

2) Then replace all the code above with this line:

```
Me.textbox1.Value = WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(Me.combobox1.Value & _
      Me.combobox2.Value, Sheets("AddProduct").Range("A2:D10"), 4, False), "N/A")
```

With not using the `WorksheetFunction` on the Vlookup, it will allow the error to pass into the IfError Check.

Edit.  Learned something new.  I would do it this way with index/match:

```
    Me.textbox1.Value = WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.Index(Sheets("AddProduct").Range("C:C"), _
    WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.combobox1.Value & Me.combobox2.Value, Sheets("AddProduct").Range("A:A") & _
    Sheets("AddProduct").Range("B:B"), 0)), "N/A")
```

This does not need a helper column and will work with what you have.

Comment: @user36896989 Learned something new and decided to edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Most `WorksheetFunction`'s are slower then simply to loop rows. Particularly if you are able to skip a part of it like in this example.

```
Sub test()
  Dim i As Long
  With Worksheets("AddProduct")
    For i = 2 To 10
      If .Cells(i, 1).Value = ComboBox1.Value And .Cells(i, 2).Value = ComboBox2.Value Then TextBox1.Value = .Cells(i, 2).Value: Exit Sub
    Next
  End With
  TextBox1.Value = "N/A"
End Sub
```

This `Sub` simply checks row by row from the second line till the tenth. If there is a match, it will put the value of the cell in the 3rd column in your textbox and exit the `Sub`. (It will skip the `TextBox1.Value = "N/A"` if a match is found)

If you need a better explanation just write a comment.